# Fill gradient color in area under line chart in Protovis 3.2

Tags: gradient, protovis, linechart

In my project, I use Protovis 3.2 to render line chart.
I want to fill gradient color in the area under line chart. Although I have tried available color functions in Protovis but they did not work.
Is there any simple solution for this problem?

Below is my code to add area into line chart

```
addArea: ->
  self = this
  @vis.add(pv.Area)
    .data(self.data[0].values)
    .bottom(1)
    .left((d) -> self.xAxisUnits(d.index))
    .height((d) -> self.yAxisUnits(d.value))
    .fillStyle(pv.ramp('black', 'red'))
    .anchor("top")
    .add(pv.Line)
    .lineWidth(2)
    .strokeStyle("#78B9E2")
  this
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm pretty sure Protovis has no support for gradient fills. You might try [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), which doesn't support gradients out of the box but offers lower-level access to the SVG element, which you can use to define an [`svg:linearGradient` fill](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html).